# iOS New array in plist with new key overwrites old array with different key

Tags: ios, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I'm using the below bit of code to add a new array into a plist, but each time I add a new array with the textfield in my app it overwrites the old one even though it has a brand new key.. any ideas?

```
- (IBAction)saveViewerItems
{
    // get paths from root direcory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    // set the variables to the values in the text fields
    self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];


    // create dictionary with values in UITextFields
    NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: data, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: (@"%@", text), nil]];

    NSString *error = nil;
    // create NSData from dictionary
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:plistDict format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

    // check is plistData exists
    if(plistData)
    {
        // write plistData to our Data.plist file
        [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is likely totally a n00b question (I'm really new to iOS development), but why would you put this data in a plist instead of using Core Data or SQLite?

Comment: The problem is that each time you are not adding data in plist. Beside this you are updating plist. So that this overides old one data

Comment: Because I'm also new and I don't really know how to do that - the data it has to hold is very simple... Is it easier to use sqlite or coredata?

Comment: How do I tell it to add it, not rewrite it?

Comment: Hello @ChrisByatt, take a look on my answer. Logic behind that is that get all objects from plist and then new object in that accessed object after that write this object in plist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the dictionaty already in the file, use:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)filePath];
```

In order to write another array in that dictionary (using a different key), use:

```
[dictionary setObject:(id)myArray forKey:(NSString *)myKey];
```

In order to write back to the file, use:

```
[dictionary writeToFile:(NSString *)filePath atomically:YES];
```

There is no need to use `NSData` class. For more info, check out [Apple NSDictionary Class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/)

Comment: what do you mean, could you explain it ?

Comment: I fixed it. Because my code created a plist every time, removing it and changing it to yours meant that if there was no plist, there was nothing to add the data to. I've fixed it by using this:

`if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
        //My original adding code
    } else {
        //your code`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
    // get paths from root direcory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath] mutableCopy];

    // set the variables to the values in the text fields
    self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];

   [plist setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: data, nil] forKey:forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: (@"%@", text)];
   [plist writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
   [plist release];
```

Comment: First get all elements in plist and then add new object in that plist object an dthen write this

Comment: Thanks for your help. FYI `release` no longer works in iOS because automatic reference counting doesn't allow it.

Comment: No problem no need to use release here !!